# Adding a Reference to the Available References Automatically

Tags: vba, excel, com

I searched on internet and read related articles but didn't find the clear answer for my problem.

I would like to summarize my work. I'm using third party program (Simpack) Com-Interface to get data and informations from Simpack program to my excel sheet.

I'm using `Set Srv = CreateObject("Simpack.Slv")` for COM implementation. But before that i should define the COM interface *.exe file from `Tools > References > Browse >  C:\Program Files\Simpack-2018x\run\bin\win64\_simpack-com-slv.exe` When i open my macro book for the first time or close it and then open. I can't use  COM library of Simpack. Because it never listed on Available References section with tick or without tick. So i should go again `Tools > References > Browse >  C:\Program Files\Simpack-2018x\run\bin\win64\_simpack-com-slv.exe` to use Simpack library.

I don't know is it related with my binding type ? Or am i missing something important but it'll be great if it's automatically doing this process `Tools > References > Browse >  C:\Program Files\Simpack-2018x\run\bin\win64\_simpack-com-slv.exe`

Kind Regards.

Comment: it gets tricky, you have to find the GUID and attempt to invoke it for the user.  Turning trust on or off for the user also gets tricky and might not be possible, this is where malicious code can be run without user authorization.  The GUID I believe is related to the product release version, so it can be tricky for users of different versions in a shared app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you need to allow programmatic access to your VBA project. On the Excel ribbon: DEVELOPER->Macro Security and tick "Trust access to VBA project object model". Then you can try this:

```
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Program Files\Simpack-2018x\run\bin\win64\_simpack-com-slv.exe"
```

Comment: Thanks MarcinSzaleniec, it worked. I want to put this Workbook_Open section, but is there any chance to control it if it is already added don't run your code but if it's not added it will run your code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps . . . .

Run this to get the GUID of your references:

```
'******** Commented out but finds dependent GUID references in the project
'Dim obj As Object
'For Each obj In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References
    'Debug.Print "Name: ", obj.Name
    'Debug.Print "FullPath: ", obj.FullPath
    'Debug.Print "Version: ", obj.Major & "." & obj.Minor
    'Debug.Print "GUID: ", obj.GUID

'Next obj
'*******************************
```

Then do something like this in your code module and sub add references . . .

```
'VBA
strGUID = "{000204EF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

'ALERT: Don't slay me for On Error Resume Next
'I was doing this fairly quickly this morning
On Error Resume Next
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid _
GUID:=strGUID, Major:=1, Minor:=0
```

I am not going to get into toggling VBA trust, that could be deemed bad behavior.

Cheers, Wookie